# Box shadow won't take effect when added by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've this code that I can't get to work.
http://jsfiddle.net/AeRV7/

The problem is that I can't add box shadow using javascript.

```
$(".first").css({"box-shadow": "0 0 5px #888;"});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon on the property (the one **inside** the quotes).

```
$(".first").css({"box-shadow": "0 0 5px #888"});
// ----------------------------------- here ^
```

Comment: yeah it does work.. there might have been some confusion because craig removed the Javascript semi-colon _and_ the one inside the string..

Comment: The last semi colon was missing in the fiddle.  Thanks for the edit @T.J. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Just as with your CSS, you need to specify the vendor prefixes:

```
$(function(){
    var val = "0px 0px 5px #888";
      $(".first").css({
          "box-shadow": val,
          "-moz-box-shadow": val,
          "-webkit-box-shadow": val
      })
});​
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AeRV7/1/)

If you need the vendor prefixes in your CSS (you did have them there), then you need them when setting the same style programmatically. In the comments, Duri says that `box-shadow` is supported on current versions without prefixes, but points out that Firefox 3.6 (which remains a widely-used browser) still needs the `-moz`.

But [Craig Swing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10673278/157247) addresses the main issue (which I only addressed above accidentally): You don't want the `;` on the value you're giving for the property. `;` in CSS *separates* style definitions from one another, it's not a part of the value.

Comment: Current versions of all browsers support `box-shadow` without vendor prefixes.

Comment: That worked, thanks. Why does the other div work without the extra -moz and -webkit? http://jsfiddle.net/whp5h/

Comment: @Oleander This works because `val` doesn't contain the trailing `;` (see Craig's answer) not because of vendor prefixes. But note that `-moz-` prefix will be necessary if you support Firefox 3.x.

Comment: @Oleander: My answer may have worked as a by-product of the fact that, while editing, I ended up retyping the value and automatically leaving out the `;` that shouldn't be there. The `;` in CSS *separates* values, it isn't a part of the value, so it shouldn't be in the string you give `.css`.